# Why can't gcc find the include path using -I option?

Tags: c, gcc, include

here's my project tree

```
project  
--bin  
--source  
----include  
------foo.h  
----main.c  
----foo.c
```

but when I run `gcc -I./source/include ./bin/main.exe ./source/*.c` it gave me **No such file or directory** error.
How can I let gcc know where's the include directory?

Comment: Since you are passing relative paths, make sure you `cd` to `project` before calling `gcc`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run gcc with the `-o` option to set the output location.

```
gcc -I./source/include -o ./bin/main.exe ./source/*.c
```